# How to target multiple instances of an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, return

I'm having some trouble defining what I'm looking for, so hopefully I won't sound to cryptic.

I'm trying to get some content out of an array from my webshop, the array stores my order information for each item in the order.

I want to return some of the values in this order information. But I'm having some trouble targeting the correct information. And since I want to return this information for each individual order_item, I need to target the unique key, and possibly write a for each function. I don't quite know where to start.

The array I'm currently returning looks something like this. How would I go about, for instance, returning both product_id's?

```
array(2) {
["d4650547c8d3536a6741b300f563a8fb"]=>
array(11) {
["product_id"]=>
int(259)
["variation_id"]=>
int(278)
["variation"]=>
array(1) {
["pa_afmetingen-liggend"]=>
string(4) "m011"
}
["quantity"]=>
int(1)
["data"]=>
object(WC_Product_Variation)#3243 (24) {  ["variation_id"]=>
int(278)
["parent"]=>
}
["product_type"]=>
string(8) "variable"
}

array(2) {
["893hg547c8d35pga6741b300f56754ud"]=>
array(11) {
["product_id"]=>
int(279)
["variation_id"]=>
int(298)
["variation"]=>
array(1) {
["pa_afmetingen-liggend"]=>
string(4) "m011"
}
["quantity"]=>
int(1)
["data"]=>
object(WC_Product_Variation)#3243 (24) {  ["variation_id"]=>
int(298)
["parent"]=>
}
["product_type"]=>
string(8) "variable"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

## Code

```
<?php
    // Sample products Array
    $my_products = array();
    $my_products[] = array('product_id' => 230, 'product_name' => 'audi');
    $my_products[] = array('product_id' => 355, 'product_name' => 'benz');

    // My products
    print_r($my_products);

    $product_ids = array();
    foreach ($my_products as $product) {
      $product_ids[] = $product['product_id'];
    }

    // MY product ids
    print_r($product_ids);

    // My first product id
    echo $my_products[0]['product_id'];

    // My second product id
    echo $my_products[1]['product_id'];
?>
```

## Output

```
// My products

      Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 230
                [product_name] => audi
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 355
                [product_name] => benz
            )

    )

// MY product ids

Array
(
    [0] => 230
    [1] => 355
)

// My first product id
230

// My second product id
355
```

Comment: That helped me out a lot! Is there a way to automate the output?
In your example you targeted each echo with the corresponding number, is there a way to echo the product_id for each entry dynamically?

Comment: yes. see the second output. (for loop)

Comment: I mean re-writing
    // My first product id
    echo $my_products[0]['product_id'];

    // My second product id
    echo $my_products[1]['product_id'];

to a single statement for all possible id's. So even if there are 15 ID's.

Comment: echo $product['product_id']; in the for each did the trick. Thanks again for the code. Plussed and chosen.